# Objective-C Calendar in simple window. How?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

My aim is to create a status bar application which will draw drop down calendar.
I'm fairly new to programming in Objective-C and I thought this might be a good project to learn the language.

Do I a draw a calendar in an `NSMenuItem(custom)` or is this the wrong approach.
Will I be using the `NSDatePicker` to draw the calendar?
I cannot find a `DatePicker` object in XCode which I can drag-drop on the canvas like in VS2010.

I want the calendar look like this:
[image]

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the following example:
[Using MAAttachedWindow with an NSStatusItem](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/)

Download the project and change the SDK to make it working:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Now add the `NSDatePicker` in Interface Builder and change its style to `graphical`.

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just get a date picker and change it's style to Graphical.

Comment: how i can do this? is this possible in iOS

Comment: @MouhamadLamaa Not sure about iOS, though I doubt it?  I haven't seen any default date picker around iOS apps.  Though I'm pretty sure there's a custom 3rd party solution to that.